# Rename specific columns across multiple data sets

Tags: r

I have a batch of data sets with many variables. I need to rename some variables in each data set to a common name, without changing the others. One issue is that each the column I want to rename is in a different location in each data set and each data set has a different number of columns. Example data and code below.

Working Data:

```
package(tidyverse)

df1 <- tribble(
~var1, ~var2, ~var3, ~var4, ~var5,
"1",   "1",   "1",   "a",   "d",
"2",   "2",   "2",   "b",   "e",
"3",   "3",   "3",   "c",   "f"
)

df2 <- tribble(
~var1, ~help, ~var3,
"1",   "1",   "1",
"2",   "2",   "2",
"3",   "3",   "3"
)

df3 <- tribble(
~var1, ~newCol, ~var3, ~help, ~var5, ~var6,
"1",   "4",     "1",   "a",   "d",   "1",
"2",   "5",     "2",   "b",   "e",   "2",
"3",   "6",     "3",   "c",   "f",   "3"
)
```

I would like to recode `help` to `var2` so it is common across the data sets. I know that I can do it individually using `dplyr` like this:

```
df2 <- df2 %>%
  rename(var2 = help)

df3 <- df3 %>%
  rename(var2 = help)
```

But I have to do this across over 100 data sets, and I would like to do it more efficiently. I was using the suggested answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28648513/changing-column-names-in-a-list-of-data-frames-in-r) post as an example, but it only works for data sets that have the same number and order of columns, which mine do not. I did try this, but it didn't work:

```
dfs <- list(df2$help = df2$help, df3$help = df3$help)

colnames <- c("var2", "var2") 

list2env(lapply(dfs, setNames, colnames), .GlobalEnv)
```

But I get the following error at the `dfs <- list(df2$help = df2$help`... command:

```
Error: unexpected '=' in "dfs <- list(df2$help ="
```

All of the examples I could find do not show how to change specific columns across data sets, only how to change all column names or [change a small number of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33567101/using-lapply-to-change-column-names-of-a-list-of-data-frames) in data sets that only have a few columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you are looking for:

```
 dat=lapply(list(df2=df2,df3=df3),function(x){names(x)[which(names(x)=="help")]="var2";x})
 list2env(dat,.GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Thanks @onyambu, but this only works if the data sets have the same number or columns and/or the column that needs to be changed is in the same location. My data sets are not like that. I updated the example data to be more realistic to my actual data. I was hoping I could "call out" each column in the data sets and rename, no matter the column location or number of columns in each data set.

Comment: so what specific name do you want to give to help in this case?

Comment: In each data set, I would like to change `help` to `var2`, no matter its location in its respective data set.

Comment: I changed it `var2` in `df3` to `newCol`. For more context, my real-world data has two different names for income: `income` and `hhIncome`. I need to change all the `hhIncome`s to `income` before I merge the data sets. Each data set has `income` and `hhIncome` in different column locations because they added and deleted variables with each new survey data collection.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161920/discussion-between-scottsmith-and-onyambu).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)

list(df1, df2, df3) %>% 
map(~if("help" %in% names(.x))rename(.x, var2=help) else .x)
```

Comment: Thanks @dmi3kno. Is there a way to rename the columns in the global environment too?

Comment: Add `%>% list2env(.GlobalEnv)` at the end?